# Find the % character in a LIKE query

Tags: php, sql, mysql, special-characters

I've an SQL database and I would like to do a query who show all the datas containing the sign "%". Normally, to find a character (for example: "z") in a database I use a query like this :

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE tag LIKE '%z%'");
```

But here, I want to found the % character, but in SQL it's a joker so when I write:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE tag LIKE '%%%'");
```

It show me all my datas. So how to found the % character in my SQL datas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can escape the `%` sign with a backslash:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE tag LIKE '%\%%'
```

Quoting from [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 8.1.1 String](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html)s:

> The `\%` and `\_` sequences are used to search for literal instances of `%` and `_` in pattern-matching contexts where they would otherwise be interpreted as wildcard characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a standard way:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE tag like '%|%%' ESCAPE '|'
```