# Finding the "&" character in SQL SERVER using a like statement and Wildcards

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to find the '&' in a string.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD LIKE ..&...
```

Things we have tried :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD LIKE '&&&'
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD LIKE '&\&&'
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD LIKE '&|&&' escape '|'
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD LIKE '&[&]&'
```

None of these give any results in `SQLServer`.
Well some give all rows, some give none.

Similar questions that didn't work or were not specific enough.

[Find the % character in a LIKE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890220/find-the-character-in-a-like-query)

[How to detect if a string contains special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558755/how-to-detect-if-a-string-contains-special-characters)

some old reference Server 2000

http://web.archive.org/web/20150519072547/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-search-for-special-characters-e-g-in-sql-server.html

Comment: Have you tried this: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD LIKE '%&%'`

Comment: Your statement contains no wildcards, thus is equivalent to `WHERE FIELD = '&'`. `&` isn't a wildcard and doesn't need to be escaped

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`&` isn't a wildcard in [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_(SQL)#LIKE), therefore no escaping is needed.

Use `%` around the value your looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD LIKE '%&%'
```

Comment: Hahaha ok, Monday morning on a thursday i guess.

Answer (score 4):

Your statement contains no wildcards, thus is equivalent to `WHERE FIELD = '&'`.

`&` isn't a special character in SQL so it doesn't need to be escaped. Just write

```
WHERE FIELD LIKE '%&%'
```

to search for entries that contain `&` somewhere in the field

Be aware though, that this will result in a full table scan as the server can't use any indexes. Had you typed `WHERE FIELD LIKE '&%'` the server could do a range seek to find all entries starting with `&`.

If you have a lot of data and can't add any more constraints, you should consider using SQL Server's full-text search to create and use and FTS index, with predicates like [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) or [FREETEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx)

Comment: thnx for your detailed answer! It was more  personal problem i guess.